# How to shape a FAB to be rounded corners button (pill shape), similar to in contact-details screen of Contacts app?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android, material-components

### Background

Initially, a FAB (floating action button) only had one shape : circle, and it only had the option to have an icon in it.

### The problem

In the past year or so, Google added various screens in its apps, that show a FAB that changes its size. For example, if you open its Contacts app and choose a contact, you a FAB as such:

[image]

And if you scroll a bit, it gets to be a circle, with just the icon in it:

[image]

I want to know how to make such a FAB, and also use similar one with just an icon in the middle (without text), meaning a rounded corners one.

Something like that:

[image]

### What I've tried and found

At first, I tried to just set the width of the FAB to be larger, but this didn't help, as it insisted on being a perfect circle (fit in a square, and without edges).

Seeing that maybe FAB can't handle this currently, I used MaterialCardViewinstead:

```
                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
```

android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="..." app:cardCornerRadius="16dp" >

```
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" app:srcCompat="..."/>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

This works, but the clicking effect is gone.

I also tried MaterialButton, but this doesn't support an icon in the middle, only on the various of the text inside.

Later, I've noticed that FAB actually does have a way to customize the shape of itself :

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton#setshapeappearance

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.java

Also, as for the expanding FAB, I've found this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/ExtendedFloatingActionButton

https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/

So looking at its code, I've found that it uses a shape of a pill, and I tried to do a similar thing to the normal FAB :

```
class PillFab @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) :
    FloatingActionButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        val shapeAppearanceModel =
            ShapeAppearanceModel(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, DEF_STYLE_RES, ShapeAppearanceModel.PILL)
        shapeAppearance = shapeAppearanceModel
    }

    companion object {
        private val DEF_STYLE_RES = R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_FloatingActionButton
    }
}
```

Sadly, this didn't work at all. It's still in a circle shape.

### The question

How can I set a FAB (with clicking effect) that has rounded corners and a single icon inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the perfect answer because you are looking for an ExtendedFAB without text.

However you can obtain something similar using a [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) changing the component’s shape using the attribute `shapeAppearanceOverlay`.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded"
            app:icon="@drawable/outline_cached_black_18dp"
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            />
```

using:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Button.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

Currenty the `app:iconGravity` doesn't support the `center` value. A workaround to center the icon is using these attrs:

```
            app:iconPadding="0dp"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
```

If you would like to override some theme attributes from a default style now you can use new `materialThemeOverlay` attribute.

Something like:

```
<style name="MtButtonStyle"
 parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
   <item name=“materialThemeOverlay”>@style/MyButtonThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonThemeOverlay">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
  <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't mind that it's not a real FAB. I just need it to look similar and behave similar. Does it have an elevation though, including animation of elevation when clicking?

Comment: @androiddeveloper It is a normal MaterialButton with its material themes. The default style represents an elevated button with a ripple animation.

Comment: Seems to work well. You forgot to mention some stuff, so I added them to your answer. Can you please explain about the last sentence? Why the need for the workaround? Will `app:iconGravity ` have "center" value?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Thanks for the editing. About app:iconGravity: it is just a workaround. Without these values the material button uses the default style and just align the icon on the left of the button also without the text. Currently there isn't a iconGravity=center and I didn't find a better solution for that.

Comment: I've noticed an issue though. When I used the sizes of width and height for the MaterialCardView solution I had, and set it to your solution, it became smaller in height. Also, not sure if it's supposed to be this way, but when disabling the button, the icon changes its color, compared to the solution I've made, that let it stay. How come? Is this supposed to be this way? Is there a way to control it? Here's a sample app to show these issues :  https://ufile.io/fr1ae5bq

Comment: MaterialButton uses colorOnSurface when it is disabled. You can configure this style in the MyButtonThemeOverlay

Comment: How? And what about the size? Can you please update the answer for a fix of these 2 issues?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Added the part about the materialThemeOverlay. About the size it is not clear the question. Is not enough android:layout_height or the style to set the preferred height?

Comment: Have you checked the project I've sent you? It shows the issue. All buttons have the same width and height being set, but using MaterialButton, it makes them look smaller.

Comment: Not yet. I have to find the time to check. In anycase MaterialButtons don't have to the same specs of AppCompatButton.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **CoordinatorLayout.Behavior** to apply shape, effect to any view in android on scroll event of Recyclerview.

Comment: I don't have anything that scrolls now, and I don't want the button to change its shape. I want it to stay on this shape. When I wrote "similar", it's about the shape, not the behavior.